# How do I make new elements draggable with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading new elements with a form.  After the elements are loaded I need to make each one draggable.  According to .on doc *"Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time."*

I've tried oh-so-many variants of .on, .click, etc but so far no luck.  I'm currently working with...

```
    $('#parent').on('change', '.thumb', function(event){
        alert('loaded');
        $('.thumb').draggable();
    });
```

...but, it doesn't attach to the new .thumb element.  How can I accomplish this?

Edit: Here's the html...

```
        <input type="file" id="parent" name="files[]" multiple />
        <output> //these spans are created after files are selected from 'file'
            <span><img class=".thumb" src="..."></span>
            <span><img class=".thumb" src="..."></span>
        </output>
```

Comment: Call `$('#child').draggable();` from the end of the code that adds the element. The `change` event doesn't occur when elements are added.

Comment: I've added the HTML to help clarify.

Comment: **How and when do you load those new elements?** the change event won't fire when elements added to `parent`

Comment: are you using $(function(){ /* your code here */})  in page or $(document).ready(function(){} ) around your code...if not it is important!! Also no idea if using ajax or not

Comment: not using ajax.  the code is executed after the DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: I guess the basic question is how could one make an element draggable that simply popped into the DOM?

Comment: Try using the jQuery UI plugin at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: That's precisely what I'm trying to do.  But I can't attach .draggable to an element until after it's created.  It's being created dynamically by non jquery code.  So I need a way to attach to an element that just pops up out of thin air.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a plugin that requires binding it's own events and DOM manipulation from within the plugin, delegation methods like on() are useless.

You need to call the draggable() method when you load new elements such as in success callback of ajax.

If you are using load()

```
 $('#myDv').load( url, function(){

   /* new html has been inserted now */

    /* in case any other active draggables will only search within $('#myDiv') for new elements that need to be called*/
     $(this).find('.dragClass').draggable();

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough detail for me to answer this question specifically, so I will attempt to guess what the problem is.

You are binding this function to the event "change" of an element with an id of "parent." The "change" function will only work in certain DOM elements, namely input, textarea, and select. (http://api.jquery.com/change/) This means that the change event will never fire if the element with id "parent" is anything but those three tags.

If this is the problem, I would suggest moving the .draggable() method to the same place you are adding "elements with a form."

Comment: You are correct, I am attaching it to an input.  Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#parent').live('change', '#child', function(event){
    alert('loaded');
    $('#child').draggable();
});
```

Comment: This popped up the "loaded" alert, but my element still isn't draggable.  I can manually make it draggable using $('.thumb').draggable() after the element is created though.

Comment: .live is used when you want to attach ivents on dynamically generated elements. Then if you can make elements draggable with  $('.thumb').draggable() why don`t you do it?

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers."
I can only do that manually from the debugger.